# Modifying Shopify Polaris Styles - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, shopify, polaris

I am trying to modify [Shopify Polaris Button](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/actions/button#navigation) components colors for React, I tried to change style.css file but nothing happened.

Any idea how to do so?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '@shopify/polaris/styles.css';
import {Page, Card, Button} from '@shopify/polaris';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Page title="Example app">
          <Card sectioned>
            <Button onClick={() => alert('Button clicked!')}>Example button</Button>
          </Card>
       </Page>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to modify `node_modules/@shopify/polaris/styles.css` , but it does not make ay effect to button color.

Comment: You should not modify files under node_modules folder.

Comment: Could use something like https://github.com/ds300/patch-package to do this and avoid forking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Polaris design system is meant to provide consistency to apps within the Shopify ecosystem. It’s not intended as an alternative to something like Bootstrap or Foundation, so changing button colors wasn’t something we built the library to support.

Comment: Ryan is correct, don't know why someone gave him a downvote?

Comment: Although my original response is still true, if you aren’t building a Shopify app, and just want to build on what we’ve provided with Polaris, your best bet is to fork the library on GitHub and make the visual changes you’d like that way.

(It’s worth noting that in any case you shouldn’t edit code in `node_modules`. Changes to packages installed there should be made upstream, wherever your package manager, e.g. NPM, is getting the source code from.)

Comment: This sucks because it's such a great library - better than anything else out there! If I fork it, I won't be able to keep up with changes easily.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint. But Polaris has never tried to be the best solution for every app.

Comment: I should also mention that since version 3.0, the Polaris license has changed to only support use for applications that integrate or interoperate with Shopify software or services. You can read more here: https://github.com/Shopify/polaris-react/blob/master/LICENSE.md Thanks for your understanding 

Comment: Until I saw1000 +  inline styles wrapped for anything Polaris, there is no way i'm using it.

Answer (score 0):

Even thou full colorizing on a button isn't possible.  You can partially modify a button like so:

```
          <div style={{color: '#bf0711'}}>
            <Button monochrome outline>
             Click Me
            </Button>
          </div>
```

This won't give you full control to like the background color but it can help to partially stylize the button.  It creates an outline and light background when you roll over.